# Why do we have $ \|\nabla P_tf(x)\| \le e^{-t}P_t\|\nabla f\|(x)? $

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-processes

We know that the semigroup of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck semigroup is that
$$
P_tf(x)=E_{Z\sim N(0,1)}[f(e^{-t}x+\sqrt{1-e^{-2t}}Z]
$$
for all smooth functions on $R^n$.

For $t\ge 0$, we have
$$
\nabla P_tf(x)=e^{-t}P_t\nabla f(x).
$$

But why do we have
$$
\|\nabla P_tf(x)\| \le e^{-t}P_t\|\nabla f\|(x)?
$$

Does it seem that they are equal? Because
$$
\|\nabla P_tf(x)\|^2=\partial_1 P_tf(x)^2+\dots+\partial_n P_tf(x)^2=e^{-t}P_t\|\nabla f\|(x)
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of Jensen's inequality.  If we look at just the first term in the expression you wrote for $\|\nabla P_t f(x)\|^2$, we have
\begin{align*}
(\partial_1 P_tf(x))^2 &= (\partial_1 \mathbb{E}[f(e^{-t}x + \sqrt{1-e^{-2t}}Z)])^2 \\
&= (\mathbb{E}[\partial_1 f(e^{-t}x + \sqrt{1-e^{-2t}}Z)])^2 \\
&= (\mathbb{E}[e^{-t} ((\nabla f)_1(e^{-t}x + \sqrt{1-e^{-2t}}Z))])^2 \\
&\le \mathbb{E}[e^{-2t} ((\nabla f)_1(e^{-t}x + \sqrt{1-e^{-2t}}Z))^2] \\
&= (e^{-t} P_t ((\nabla f)_1(x))^2)
\end{align*}

We used the fact that $f$ is smooth to justify moving the partial derivative inside the expectation in the second equality.